# php paging script for a search engine

Tags: php, search-engine

i have a paging script

```
for($page = 1; $page <= $maxPage; $page++)
{
   if ($page == $pageNum)
   {
      $nad .= " $page "; // no need to create a link to current page
   }
   else
   {
      $nad .= " <a href=\"/search?search&q=".$_GET["q"]."&page=$page\">$page</a> ";
   }
}
```

that will show pages for the search query. I want to limit the amount of pages it shows to 5, because currently it shows every page, which is a problem,
say if there were 5000 rows and 5 rows per page, it would show 1000 pages. How do i limit that to 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`min()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)** and the **[`max()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)** functions:

```
$firstPage = max(1, $pageNum-5);
$lastPage = min($maxPage, $pageNum+5);
for($page = $firstPage; $page <= $lastPage; $page++)
{
  // no changes here
}
```

Comment: @user2166538 - My bad. I corrected my answer. *I typed `min` instead of `max` and otherwise.* I tested my code this time, it'll work :)